# Wrong condition checking with input in LibGDX.scene2d

Tags: java, if-statement, libgdx, conditional-statements, scene2d

I'm building a GUI for my game with LibGDX.scene2d.ui and I have a problem when I'm trying to handle inputs. I have the following code to make something happen when button is pressed but it doesn't work:

```
enterButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int p, int b) {
            Gdx.app.log("touched", "down");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int p, int b) {
            Gdx.app.log("touched", "up");
            if(x > enterButton.getX() && x < enterButton.getRight() && y > enterButton.getY() && y < enterButton.getTop()) {
                Gdx.app.log("cond", "cursor on actor");
                if(validate(loginField.getText(), passField.getText())) {
                    Gdx.app.log("cond", "validated");
                    openMenu();
                }
            }
            Gdx.app.log("untouched", "up");
        }
    });
```

But practically same code work correctly:

```
registerButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int p, int b) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int p, int b) {
            if(x > registerButton.getX() && x < registerButton.getRight() && y > registerButton.getY() && y < registerButton.getTop()) {
                registerWindow.setVisible(true);
                baseWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

After single click on the enterButton I'm getting this output made with LibGDX logging:

```
touched: down
touched: up
untouched: up
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: what is the issue here, what do you want to get ? can you explain ?

Comment: Just use ChangeListener and override the changed method to react to button presses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a ClickListener to check if the touch is within bounds or not, like so:

```
enterButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (isOver()) {
            if(validate(loginField.getText(), passField.getText())) {
                openMenu();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can also try setting the debug flag on the Actor so that you can see where the click bounds actually are by using `enterButton.debug();`